# How do I add my Expandablelistview to my main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, expandablelistview, main-activity

This is my EXPlistview :

```
public class ExpandableList extends MainActivity {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, GroupInfo> subjects = new LinkedHashMap<String, GroupInfo>();
    private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList = new ArrayList<GroupInfo>();

    private CustomAdapter listAdapter;
    private ExpandableListView simpleExpandableListView;
    // private Button ShoppingCart;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_list);


        // add data for displaying in expandable list view
        loadData();

        //get reference of the ExpandableListView
        simpleExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleExpandableListView);
        // create the adapter by passing your ArrayList data
        listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ExpandableList.this, deptList);
        // attach the adapter to the expandable list view
        simpleExpandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //expand all the Groups
        expandAll();

        // setOnChildClickListener listener for child row click
        simpleExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                //get the group header
                GroupInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);
                //get the child info
                ChildInfo detailInfo = headerInfo.getProductList().get(childPosition);

                return false;
            }
        });
        // setOnGroupClickListener listener for group heading click
        simpleExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                //get the group header
                GroupInfo headerInfo = deptList.get(groupPosition);

                return false;
            }


        });

    }

    //method to expand all groups
    private void expandAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            simpleExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    //method to collapse all groups
    private void collapseAll() {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            simpleExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }

    //load some initial data into out list
    private void loadData() {

        addProduct("Dairy", "Cheese");
        addProduct("Dairy", "Milk");

        addProduct("Meat", "Chicken");
        addProduct("Meat", "Fish");

        addProduct("Electronics", "Camera");
        addProduct("Electronics", "Refrigerator");

        addProduct("Fruits", "Oranges");
        addProduct("Fruits", "Apples");

        addProduct("Vegetables", "Broccoli");
        addProduct("Vegetables", "Carrot");

    }
    //here we maintain our products in various departments
    private int addProduct(String department, String product) {

        int groupPosition = 0;

        //check the hash map if the group already exists
        GroupInfo headerInfo = subjects.get(department);
        //add the group if doesn't exists
        if (headerInfo == null) {
            headerInfo = new GroupInfo();
            headerInfo.setName(department);
            subjects.put(department, headerInfo);
            deptList.add(headerInfo);
        }

        //get the children for the group
        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = headerInfo.getProductList();
        //size of the children list
        int listSize = productList.size();
        //add to the counter
        listSize++;

        //create a new child and add that to the group
        ChildInfo detailInfo = new ChildInfo();
        detailInfo.setName(product);
        productList.add(detailInfo);
        headerInfo.setProductList(productList);

        //find the group position inside the list
        groupPosition = deptList.indexOf(headerInfo);
        return groupPosition;
    }
}
```

---

Here's my Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupInfo> deptList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.deptList = deptList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
        return productList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ChildInfo detailInfo = (ChildInfo) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_items, null);
        }

        TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
        childItem.setText(detailInfo.getName().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        ArrayList<ChildInfo> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getProductList();
        return productList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return deptList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return deptList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        GroupInfo headerInfo = (GroupInfo) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_items, null);
        }

        TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textgroup);
        heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
```

---

And here is my main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton StoreLayout, navigation, promotion, products, shoppinglist;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Shoppinglist= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.shoppinglist);
        Shoppinglist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Expandablelistview.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the given MainActivity according to your requirement. Hope this will serve your purpose.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"HomeFragment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HomeFragment HF = new HomeFragment ();
        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, HF, HF.getTag()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ExpandableListView) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"ExpandableLVFragment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ExpandableLVFragment ELVF = new ExpandableLVFragment ();
        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, ELVF, ELVF.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_ListView) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}